# Limiting anonymous ratings intelligently?

Tags: php, api, rest, rate-limiting

This is an odd one for me.  I have a client who wants a 5 star anonymous rating system for their site.  I decided instead of using somebody else's solution now would be a good time to dig into backbone/underscore, using this as a jumping in point.

The issue is that I'm not sure how I should rate limit anonymous connections to avoid abuse of the rating system?

My initial thought was to do 1 rating every 2 seconds, 15 ratings a minute, and 200 an hour allowances to each IP.  This has the issue of possibly limiting those under a large NAT though.  I could fix that with mixing in the user agent, but then I run into the issue that they can easily fake that every request to circumvent the entire limiting system.  I could try cookies, but again, they're easily removed.

Any thoughts on a proven solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to identify different anonymous users by combination of IP and user agent. About rate limiting - 1 rating every 2 seconds is too often, how about 1 rating per day?

Comment: As I had said, user agent is a good idea unless the bot just generates one every request, which would make the entire system pointless, and isn't difficult to do.

Comment: Right, so I suggested to combine it with IP to overcome this problem. Of course, bot can change proxies on each request, but then your only option is to allow only registered users to vote.